# How to find the song title, artist name in android so that I can display all the attributes separately in my app?

Tags: android, media-player, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am trying to create a `Media Player` app using the `MediaPLayer` class and all that stuff. I was able to display the song file name in one line. I am finding it difficult to separate the song title, song name, movie name and display it separately in a `TextView`.

Comment: what you tried? where is your code?

Comment: You need to use IDv3 tag libraries: Check here http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/ and here http://entagged.sourceforge.net/

And please do some search before you post your question.

Answer (score 1):

You needed to search over internet before asking any question.

```
     String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
     String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION};

     cursor = this.managedQuery(
             MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection,null, null);

     private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();

     while(cursor.moveToNext()){
         songs.add(cursor.getString(0) + "||" + cursor.getString(1) + "||" +
                 cursor.getString(2) + "||" + cursor.getString(3) + "||" +
                 cursor.getString(4) + "||" + cursor.getString(5));
     }
```

---

Link To See [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/list-all-music-files),and [this](http://androidsamples.blogspot.in/2009/06/displaying-list-of-music-files-stored.html),and [this](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=440),and [this for custom listview](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)